# Non-parametric confidence interval (Chebyshev inequality)

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

I want to solve the following exercise:

> Given is an expected value of random variable X, E(X) = 200 at time
> point t and a standard deviation of 50.
>
> (a) Find the 95% confidence interval of the random variable
> at this time point t.
>
> (b) What is the probability that the value of the Random Variable is at least 300?

There is no probability distribution and no further data given.

**My approach:**
As one of the comments points out, I am using Chebyshev's theorem:

$$P(|X-\mu|\ge k\sigma)\le\frac{1}{k^2}$$

I find the following results - are these correct?

(a) For $1 - \frac{1}{k^2}$ = 0.95 I find k = 4.4721 and hence with
$k\sigma-\mu \leq X \leq k\sigma+\mu$ I find the lower bound of 23.6 and the upper bound of 423.6068 for the 95% confidence interval.

(b) Not quite sure here, but my approach would be using
$$|X-200|\ge 100$$ with $\sigma = 50$ we get $\frac{1}{2^2}$ and hence
a probability of 25% for a value of X being at least 300.
Is that correct?

Comment: In order to provide context, can you give a definition of the confidence interval of a random variable. Do you have data? Can you show what you have tried, and where your're stuck?

Comment: One approach that comes to my mind is Chebyehev's Theorem, which could be used to find an interval that **at least** $95\%$ of the time points t fall in. No underlying distribution required.

Comment: @WaveX Is my approach correct?

Comment: For a), I am getting the lower bound to be -23.6 by calculation. However, because of the nature of the variable we are dealing with, time, which will never be negative, we can substitute in $0$ for the lower bound.

Comment: @WaveX X is the value of some random variable at time t (X itself is not time) - and is it not 4.4721*50 - 200 = 23.6 (which is positive)? Also, is my approach to (b) correct?

Comment: Oh okay, my mistake on the kind of random variable. But the confidence interval is $\mu \pm k \sigma$

Comment: @WaveX thank you - how about (b)?